# git clone --recurse-submodules fails silently

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules

I have added a submodule to one of my repositories hosted on GitLab. In my browser GitLab displays the correct submodule@commit entry and the `.gitmodules` also looks okay. However, if I clone the repository using `--recurse-submodules`, the folder which should contain the submodule is empty.

I realize that this is impossible to diagnose without further information (which I cannot provide) but all I'd like to know here is how to go about debugging this myself since git fails to provide any information on what's gone wrong.

EDIT: I believe I've figured it out. I'm on Windows (which I forgot to tag, sorry about that) and my .gitmodules contained submodule paths using escaped backslashes (which I thought was correct), manually changing those to forward slashes fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you try to call `git submodule update`, possibly with `--init`?

Comment: As a general rule, to trace what Git is doing, set the environment variable `GIT_TRACE` to `1`: `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this after cloning you repository:

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update --remote
```

Comment: Both commands have no effect in my case (no output and submodule directory is still empty) and enabling GIT_TRACE produces nothing helpful. I'm using a console emulator on Windows and I'm starting to suspect that the issue is caused by that, unfortunately I can't test this on a Linux machine at the moment.

Comment: This also happens when try to clone the repo with an IDE with git integration, so this might just be Windows specific.